# Why is my form's submit button not working?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I am modifying a WP plugin (PHP; latest version of WP). It has a form where a user can ask a question. It came with it's own submit button. I found an action hook where I can add my own code to the form, so I added Braintree's simplest payment form - the DropIn UI. [This is a screenshot of what both forms look like when I set them up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckX7c.jpg).

**The problem:**

The "Post question" button that came with the plugin is not working and I suspect that it is due to the presence of the second form.

**What I've tried:**

I removed bits and pieces of the code I added to try and single out what could be causing this and it came down to the DropIn's form code itself. The presence of a 2nd form on this page is causing an issue.

**My question:** What could cause submit issues when 2 forms are present on one page?

---

**Note** - I used an action hook to insert my code to a function that described itself as the main plugin's form footer. I am getting the feeling that this is a form nesting problem.

**my function that creates the Braintree form:**

```
class FD_Braintree_Form
{
    public function fd_bt_form()
        {

            echo 

                '<form id="checkout" action="/process-trans.php" method="post">

                  <p>
                    <label><font size="5">Amount:</font></label>
                    <input type="text" size="4" name="amount" />
                  </p>

                  <div id="payment-form"></div>

                  <input type="submit" value="Pay" />

                </form>';

        }
}
```

**my function that generates the Braintree form:**

```
class Find_Do_For_Anspress
{
   add_action('ap_form_bottom_ask_form', array( $this, 'fd_bt_form_html')); //This is where I use the action hook to insert my code into the plugin's form_footer()

   public function fd_bt_form_html()
        {       
            $class_bt_token = new Braintree_ClientToken();
            $clientToken = $class_bt_token->generate();

            ?>
            <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>
            <script>

                braintree.setup(
                '<?php echo $clientToken ?>',
                'dropin', {
                  container: 'payment-form',
                }); 

            </script>
            <?php       

            $class_bt_form = new FD_Braintree_Form();
            $bt_form = $class_bt_form->fd_bt_form();

            echo $bt_form;
        }
}
```

**plugin's main code that generates the question form:**

```
function ap_ask_form($editing = false){
    global $editing_post;

    $is_private = false;
    if($editing){
        $is_private = $editing_post->post_status == 'private_post' ? true : false;
    }

    $args = array(
        'name'              => 'ask_form',
        'is_ajaxified'      => true,
        'submit_button'     => ($editing ? __('Update question', 'ap') : __('Post question', 'ap')),
        'fields'            => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'title',
                'label' => __('Title', 'ap'),
                'type'  => 'text',
                'placeholder'  => __('Question in one sentence', 'ap'),
                'desc'  => __('Write a meaningful title for the question.', 'ap'),
                'value' => ( $editing ? $editing_post->post_title : sanitize_text_field( @$_POST['title'] ) ),
                'order' => 5,
                'attr' => 'data-action="suggest_similar_questions"',
                'autocomplete' => false,
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'title',
                'type'  => 'custom',
                'order' => 5,
                'html' => '<div id="similar_suggestions"></div>'
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'description',
                'label' => __('Description', 'ap'),
                'type'  => 'editor',
                'desc'  => __('Write description for the question.', 'ap'),
                'value' => ( $editing ? apply_filters('the_content', $editing_post->post_content) : @$_POST['description']  ),
                'settings' => apply_filters( 'ap_ask_form_editor_settings', array(
                    'textarea_rows'     => 8,
                    'tinymce'           => ap_opt('question_text_editor') ? false : true,
                    'quicktags'         => ap_opt('question_text_editor') ? true : false ,
                    'media_buttons'     =>false,
                )),
            ),
            array(
                'name'  => 'ap_upload',
                'type'  => 'custom',
                'html' => ap_post_upload_form(),
                'order' => 10
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'parent_id',
                'type'  => 'hidden',
                'value' => ( $editing ? $editing_post->post_parent : get_query_var('parent')  ),
                'order' => 20
            )
        ),
    );

    if(ap_opt('allow_private_posts'))
        $args['fields'][] = array(
            'name' => 'is_private',
            'type'  => 'checkbox',
            'desc'  => __('Only visible to admin and moderator.', 'ap'),
            'value' => $is_private,
            'order' => 12,
            'show_desc_tip' => false
        );

    if(ap_opt('recaptcha_site_key') == '')
        $reCaptcha_html = '<div class="ap-notice red">'.__('reCaptach keys missing, please add keys', 'ap').'</div>';
    else
        $reCaptcha_html = '<div class="g-recaptcha" id="recaptcha" data-sitekey="'.ap_opt('recaptcha_site_key').'"></div><script type="text/javascript"
src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl='.get_locale().'&onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"  async defer></script><script type="text/javascript">var onloadCallback = function() {
        widgetId1 = grecaptcha.render("recaptcha", {
          "sitekey" : "'.ap_opt('recaptcha_site_key').'"
        });
      };</script>';

    if(ap_opt('enable_recaptcha'))
        $args['fields'][] = array(
            'name' => 'captcha',
            'type'  => 'custom',
            'order' => 100,
            'html' => $reCaptcha_html
        );

    /**
     * FILTER: ap_ask_form_fields
     * Filter for modifying $args
     * @var array
     * @since  2.0
     */
    $args = apply_filters( 'ap_ask_form_fields', $args, $editing );

    if($editing){
        $args['fields'][] = array(
            'name'  => 'edit_post_id',
            'type'  => 'hidden',
            'value' => $editing_post->ID,
            'order' => 20
        );
    }

    $form = new AnsPress_Form($args);

    echo $form->get_form();
    echo ap_post_upload_hidden_form();
}
```

**the plugin's "form footer" code and the action hook I used:**

```
private function form_footer()
    {
        ob_start();
        /**
         * ACTION: ap_form_bottom_[form_name]
         * action for hooking captcha and extar fields
         * @since 2.0.1
         */
        do_action('ap_form_bottom_'. $this->name);
        $this->output .= ob_get_clean();

        $this->output .= '<button type="submit" class="ap-btn ap-btn-submit">'.$this->args['submit_button'].'</button>';

        if(@$this->args['show_cancel'] === true)
            $this->output .= '<button type="button" class="ap-btn ap-btn-cancel">'.__('Cancel', 'ap').'</button>';

        $this->output .= '</form>';
    }
```

**the hidden upload function:**

```
function ap_post_upload_hidden_form(){
    if(ap_opt('allow_upload_image'))
        return '<form id="hidden-post-upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" style="display:none">
            <input type="file" name="post_upload_image" class="ap-upload-input">
            <input type="hidden" name="ap_ajax_action" value="upload_post_image" />
            <input type="hidden" name="ap_form_action" value="upload_post_image" />
            <input type="hidden" name="__nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce( 'upload_image_'.get_current_user_id()).'" />
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="ap_ajax" />
        </form>';
}
```

**the HTML that houses the plugin's ask form code:**

```
<div class="ap-tab-container">
        <div id="ap-form-main" class="active ap-tab-item">
            <?php ap_ask_form(); ?>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using 1 button to submit 2 forms?

Comment: Save all your changes, restore the state of the code to what it was before you started and see if the problem was there to begin with.

Comment: @user2182349 the problem was not there to begin with. The plugin worked as expected since installation. The error is due to my adding Braintree code and I am trying to understand why.

Comment: @Sina No, I am not. *However* the "Pay" button is now submitting both forms. How is it that a form's unique submit button can also submit a different form?

Comment: Can you validate the HTML?  You may have mismatched tags.  You should also check to see how the forms are being submitted, you may need to put a different id or class on your button.  It would help if you posted your code.

Comment: Yup, posting some code would help lots.

Comment: When do you use fd_bt_form_html ?  I see it's definition but not it's use.  I agree form nesting looks likely (as mentioned in my answer)

Comment: I've modified my answer to give you a working solution.  but, you will have to modify the plugin's code (1 line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: The problem in the case is the action hook you are using is placing your form inside of the plugin's form.  You need to use a different action hook (or you need to get hacky with this one.)

The plugin you are using does not provide an appropriate action hook to put the form where you are trying to put it (after the ask_form).  You will have to modify the plugin code for this to work.  If you are willing to modify the plugin code, you would do this:

Modify the plugins form footer method:

```
private function form_footer()
{
    ob_start();
    /**
     * ACTION: ap_form_bottom_[form_name]
     * action for hooking captcha and extar fields
     * @since 2.0.1
     */
    do_action('ap_form_bottom_'. $this->name);
    $this->output .= ob_get_clean();

    $this->output .= '<button type="submit" class="ap-btn ap-btn-submit">'.$this->args['submit_button'].'</button>';

    if(@$this->args['show_cancel'] === true)
        $this->output .= '<button type="button" class="ap-btn ap-btn-cancel">'.__('Cancel', 'ap').'</button>';

    $this->output .= '</form>';

    //MODIFICATION added action
    do_action('ap_form_aftercustom_'. $this->name); 

}
```

Then, modify your fd_bt_form_html function:

```
class Find_Do_For_Anspress
{
   //MODIFICATION use the new action
   add_action('ap_form_aftercustom_ask_form', array( $this, 'fd_bt_form_html')); //This is where I use the action hook to insert my code into the plugin's form_footer()

   public function fd_bt_form_html()
        {       
            $class_bt_token = new Braintree_ClientToken();
            $clientToken = $class_bt_token->generate();

            ?>
            <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>
            <script>

                braintree.setup(
                '<?php echo $clientToken ?>',
                'dropin', {
                  container: 'payment-form',
                }); 

            </script>
            <?php       

            $class_bt_form = new FD_Braintree_Form();
            $bt_form = $class_bt_form->fd_bt_form();

            echo $bt_form;
        }
}
```

-End Edit-

My original feedback before I got the extra info:

I think there are two likely culprits here (without seeing your code).

1. You put a form inside of a form.
2. Your buttons/submits specifies a form by name.

## #1 Example

```
<form>
   <input ...>
   <input ...>
   <input type="submit" form="SomeForm" value="Submit Form 1">

   <form>
      <input ...>
      <input ...>
   <input type="submit" form="SomeForm" value="Submit Form 2">
   </form>    
</form>
```

## #2 Example

```
<form name="SomeForm" id="SomeForm">
   <input form="SomeForm" ...>
   <input form="SomeForm" ...>
   <input type="submit" form="SomeForm" value="Submit Form 1">
</form>

<form>
   <input form="SomeForm" ...>
   <input form="SomeForm" ...>
   <input type="submit" form="SomeForm" value="Submit Form 2">
</form>
```

Here is an example of form nesting that will work on some browsers in html5 (not recommended solution).

```
<form name="SomeForm" id="SomeForm">
   <input form="SomeForm" ...>
   <input form="SomeForm" ...>
   <input type="submit" form="SomeForm" value="Submit Form 1">

   <form name="SomeForm2" id="SomeForm2">
      <input form="SomeForm2"  ...>
      <input form="SomeForm2" ...>
       <input type="submit" form="SomeForm2" value="Submit Form 2">
   </form>    
</form>
```

Wordpress is a very popular and very powerful tool.  However, whenever I am forced to look at it's code, I am reminded why I don't use it.  This is the worst PHP code of any well-adapted program I have seen.  It is downright awful.  If **any of the people reading this are learning PHP** and using Wordpress as an example, please do yourself a favor and use ANY other source of PHP example code.  **Wordpress is utter garbage**, code-wise.

Comment: Yes I also think it's the problem in example #1. Take a look at the edit I just made - I added the form footer code that came with the plugin. Inside it is the action hook I used.

Comment: From the code you uploaded, I don't see the second form being used anywhere.  (See my comment to your original question).  I might need to see the `AnsPress_Form` class and the `ap_post_upload_hidden_form` function

Comment: Oh, I apologize. I left out where I actually use the action hook. I'll edit.

Comment: Hmm..the `Anspress_Form` class code is very long...and on the subject of  the hidden form - I added the function for it. It seems to just have to deal with image uploading?

Comment: Let's assume that the problem is that of Example #1. Is there a way to properly nest 1 form inside another?

Comment: Not reliably.  You can use form names in html5 on most browsers.  But really I think you just want to "un-nest" them ideally.  I'll post an example where nesting works in HTML5.

Comment: Can you at least post the `get_form` function from the class?  Everything else looks good.

Comment: I see the problem now (sorry I'm not a WP pro so it took a second to figure out all these pieces).  You can't use the footer action hook.  Updating my answer...

Comment: Your recommendation for the new `add_action()` looks promising, I'll test it out tomorrow. You made me curious about better-written PHP code. Do you have any examples of PHP coded applications that are way better to learn from?

Comment: Unfortunately, the nature of PHP means that a lot of the code out there is less than stellar.  Let me try to think of / find a well written PHP program that you can use for an example.  The Balanced API was decent iirc (https://www.balancedpayments.com/) but they look to be folding.  (Disclaimer, the following product is written by me): The ActiveWAFL Framework (http://activewafl.com) has what I think to be very well written OO PHP.  Here is an old presentation I did on the topic: http://goo.gl/19EC5D although if I were to do that presentation again I'd revise several of my statements.